# Excel Formula, Remove last \ and Child Path from String

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a pathname that uses backslashes as delimiters and ends with a backslash in cell `B5`, e.g., `\\stack\over\flow\`. 
I would like to reduce it to `\\stack\over\`. 
I need a formula to remove the last `\` and child path component
from my full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C5, enter formula :

```
=REPLACE(B5,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(B5,"\","@",LEN(B5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B5,"\",""))-1))+1,99,"")
```

Comment: thanks BOSCO!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Building on [bosco_yip’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1619914/150988), simplifying it and explaining it:

```
=LEFT(B5,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(B5,"\","|",LEN(B5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B5,"\",""))-1)))
```

- `SUBSTITUTE(B5,"\","")` removes all the backslashes in `B5`
  (by replacing them with empty strings). 
  So, for example, if `B5` is `\\stack\over\flow\`,
  this would be `stackoverflow`.
- `LEN(B5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B5,"\",""))` is a common trick
  for counting the number of backslashes in `B5`. 
  We subtract 1 from that to get the number of the second-to-last backslash.
- `SUBSTITUTE(B5,"\","|", <the above> )`
  replaces the second-to-last backslash with a `|` (vertical bar).
- `FIND("|", <the above> )`
  finds the *position* of the `|`,
  which (presumably / hopefully) was the second-to-last backslash. 
  Naturally there will be a problem here
  if `B5` already contains any vertical bars,
  but note that `|` is not allowed in Windows pathnames. 
  (By contrast, `@` ***is*** a valid Windows filename character.)
- `LEFT(B5, <the above> )` gets the value of `B5`
  up through (and including) the second-to-last backslash.

Note that, if `B5` contains only one `\`
(e.g., `\`, `foo\bar` or `\Program Files`), the above will get an error. 
If `B5` is `\\` or `\\stack`, then the result will be `\`. 
[bosco_yip’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1619914/150988) behaves the same.